# NameError: name 'scipy' is not defined

Tags: python

I keep getting the "NameError: name 'scipy' is not defined", when I know I've downloaded and imported scipy.

Any tips?

Here's my code:

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate

exact = scipy.integrate.ode(eq1)
print(exact)
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Yeah, like copperfield said, integrate.ode, not scipy.integrate.

Comment: You have no `import scipy` in this code...

Comment: Can you clarify how you know that scipy is installed and you actually can import it? Your error suggests otherwise.

Comment: @cricket_007 the error the OP get is NameError, that means that the import was successful, otherwise it would be ImportError

Answer (score 4):

try with

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate

exact = integrate.ode(eq1)   #notice, no scipy
print(exact)
```

the problem is that you [import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) the module `scipy.integrate` and bound it to the variable `integrate` with the instruction `as`, that is why you get the name error in `scipy.integrate.ode(eq1)`, `scipy` is not in your namespace, just `integrate`;

if you want to include `scipy` it then import it as

```
import scipy
```

so you can use its other features

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import scipy
exact = integrate.ode(eq1)
print(exact)
```

or just without the `as`

```
import scipy.integrate 

exact = scipy.integrate.ode(eq1)
print(exact)
```

Comment: Makes senses now

Answer (score 2):

Import scipy and use its methods using dot operator.

import scipy

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it occurs when we missed installing ***scipy***. You can install it using the following command:

```
 pip install scipy
```

After successful installation you can import it as follows:

```
import scipy
```